# OAUTH: Facebook API throws error because of wrong redirect-url parameter

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0

I am using FB Login on my site and the integration works seamlessly for more than two years.

For a few days now, though, I am seeing occasionally this error in my log:

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
> domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains
> of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

The URL that is called looks like this:

```
https://www.mydomain/de/oauth2/facebook?code=abcdefgxyz&deferred_redirect_uri&state=12345
```

I have no clue what the parameter `deferred_redirect_uri` is (it is not a valid standard parameter) or where it comes from, but I guess this is the reason why the login fails.

It is important to notice that the FB login still works wonderfully in 99,99 percent of the cases, so all the right URLs are present in the APP setup in the developer backend on Facebook. The setup absolutely works.

So I wonder where this rare error comes from and if this is some kind of hacking attempt?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, we are experiencing the same problem because when the URL contains `deferred_redirect_uri`, the login fails and returns that error.

The fix that we found working is a little bit tricky, and it shouldn't be used as a "final" solution: in `Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php` in the `FacebookRedirectLoginHelper` class, there is the `getAccessToken` function that calls static function `removeParamsFromUrl` of `FacebookUrlManipulator`.
That function basically removes all the unwanted params before getting the OAuth2 token, so after we've added the weird parameter to that array the login error is gone.

```
public function getAccessToken($redirectUrl = null)
{
    if (!$code = $this->getCode()) {
        return null;
    }

    $this->validateCsrf();
    $this->resetCsrf();

    $redirectUrl = $redirectUrl ?: $this->urlDetectionHandler->getCurrentUrl();
    // At minimum we need to remove the 'code', 'enforce_https' and 'state' params
    $redirectUrl = FacebookUrlManipulator::removeParamsFromUrl($redirectUrl, ['code', 'enforce_https', 'state', 'deferred_redirect_uri']);

    return $this->oAuth2Client->getAccessTokenFromCode($code, $redirectUrl);
}
```

Comment: Hahaha, great minds think alike: This is EXACTLY what I thought would do the trick, but I thought, I'd have a look if somebody has a better solution than this. But the question remains: Where does this parameter come from?

Comment: That's a really good question because that issue came out of nowhere on Saturday morning for us. There's also a bug opened on Facebook support, but no additional info on the error. https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1039393886517645/